# Most frequently used programming language commands in Python

Tags: programming

I am looking for a dataset which lists the most often used commands for Python in terms of their relative frequency.

Sample result could look like:

```
| Function name| Relative Frequency 
|:-------------|-------------------:|
| function     |                12% |
| print        |                 8% |    
| apply        |                 3% |
```